# YouTube Player API android does not automatically change the video quality

Tags: android-youtube-api

Hope anyone can help me

We are developing an Android app that integrates the latest YouTube API Player. Everything seems to be ok when user wants to load a video (using the video Id), and the user is able to visualize it.

However, we have identified in our lab an strange behaviour in the YouTube player **when the quality of the network where the user is located gets worse**. We thought that the YouTube player would automatically adapt the video quality depending on the network conditions (no quality selection is done, thinking that by default is set to automatic), however it does not, but the native YouTube App does.

Let me describe the test performed where we have observed this behaviour:

1. An android device with the native YouTube App and our app installed and connected to our WLAN network
2. The WLAN network provides access to internet and we can inject some impairments on that network (i.e. reduce the bandwith)
3. Configure excellent bandwith in the nertwork
4. Start the video and visualize some seconds
5. Configure bad bandwith (i.e. 256 kbit/s) in the network
6. After a few seconds:
     a. YouTube App stalls just a little, then decrease the quality and continue playing the video.
     b. AT4-App stalls longer to continue playing at the initial quality.

We think we already use the Youtube API at the most so we don’t know if we can upgrade our app to behave exactly like native YouTube App, because it does not make any sense that the API has less functionality that the native App (which is supposed to rely on the same APIs).

Thks

Comment: Unfortunately we did not receive any reply from YouTube Google guys concerning to this issue. Do not know why :S We finally decided to change our implementation and use YouTube iFrame API.

Comment: have you solved this yet? I am having the same problem